# Domain name without www is not working

Tags: web, dns, cloudflare

Everything was working perfectly, but now, without www I end up with the following page :

f493168dba83126a

I am using cloudflare and it redirects to the same ip, and here is my apache configuration for this website

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainfolder
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

With of course domain replaced by my domain.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be related to CloudFlare, this would be related to your underlying web server. If you have managed hosting I'd suggest speaking with your hosting provider. Sounds like you don't have manages hosting though, and you're configuring the server yourself.

If you're still seeing this issue can you share the specific domain name? It'd be helpful to run some curls against the site to see the responses being returned by the server.